# Get method fetches the field value where POST method cant? (PHP)

Tags: php, post, get

I've a form with POST method like

```
<form name="imgbnk" action="imgbnk.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
select the image <input type="file" name="imgloc">
```

where in `imgbnk.php` am retrieving them as `$filename=$_POST["imgloc"];`

problem is

1. when I use `POST` method, `$filename` is not getting any value from form `imgbnk` where as if I use `GET` method, `$filename` is returning file name in a expected, I wanna know why `POST` cant retrieve the same.
2. `$size=getimagesize($filename);` comes up with a warning like
    `Warning: getimagesize(Hydrangeas.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\imgbnk\imgbnk.php` when `GET` method is used.
3. If I use `POST` its saying that `Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty`.

Please help me to understand why this happens, task is to get the complete properties of an image and to store it locally.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried using $_FILES?

Comment: I tried using `$_FILES` where that is throwing every of form field as `Notice: Undefined index` along with `Warning: getimagesize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given `

Comment: how can I get weight of an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to do this way

For retrieving image properties  use

```
$name=$_FILES['imgloc']['name'];
$size=$_FILES['imgloc']['size'];
$type=$_FILES['imgloc']['type'];
$tmp_path=$_FILES['imgloc']['tmp_name'];
$error=$_FILES['imgloc']['error'];
```

and for retrieving other form field details use

```
$title=$_POST['title'];
$description=$_POST['desc'];
$keywords=$_POST['keywords'];
$catagiri=$_POST['catagiri'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use POST for uploading files. And then you use $_FILES to access the properties of the uploaded file, not $_POST.

See this manual entry for more details: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $_POST you can use [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) .Will get all the properties of file. $_POST cannot use for this file uploading

Answer (score 0):

you can get file name in `$_FILES['imgloc']['name']`...

Comment: Thanks this works but I've other fields like `$title=$_FILES["title"];`
 for these its throwing `Notice: Undefined index: title`

Comment: but why did you use "title"? print_r($_FILES) for better understanding.

Comment: I wanna access those filed values, not for just printing them